# C++ cin input stored directly to pass by reference variable - dangerous?

Tags: c++, security, reference

Is it dangerous to have cin input directly assigned to a double variable that is passed by reference? If so, what measures can I take to defend against dangerous input - aside from not passing by reference.

Example below:

```
void samplefunction(double &var1, double &var2)
{
    cout << "Enter something: ";
    cin >> var1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter something: ";
    cin >> var2;
}
```

Comment: @Colonel - In addition to stix's answer below, you need to validate what has been read. Its not clear to me that `samplefunction` is validating the input.

Comment: validate as in check if the input was successfully stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, is no, as the cin >> operator will only read as much data as it requires to fill the type. The rest is discarded until the next whitespace. You may not get correct values, for example if someone feeds in "ABCDEF" instead of "1.0," but you won't have to worry about a buffer overflow.

Comment: What if someone does this?
double* d = new double;
double& dr = *d;
delete d;
sampleFunction(dr, dr);

Comment: Any time you use invalid pointers, bad things are going to happen. I'm not sure what the relevance is of your example is to the OP's question though, as the OP seems concerned about whether or not the user can cause undefined or insecure behavior through input on cin.